# ExtJS 4 and grid questions

Tags: extjs4

I can't find proper answer for two questions concerning grid (lot of different answers, no one good):

- how can I center texts in grid cells vertically;
- how can I display vertical lines as well as horizontal.

Be so kind as to prompt me, please.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Apply custom css to your grid. Something like this:

```
#GridId div.x-grid-cell-inner { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: @TobySpeight I must have 50 reputations to add a comment to other posts.

Comment: Try to apply css like this to your grid. #GridId div.x-grid-cell-inner {
    text-align: center;
}

Comment: @Vel It's much better to edit the code into your answer than to put the code in a comment. In the comment, it's very unlikely to be noticed, as well as being difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

To center the text in the center of the column use the `align` property, this way `align: 'center'`. Notice that the email column is centralized.
In the case of vertical lines it is more complicated.
*ExtJS* has a setting to show the lines of the column `columnLines: true`, but doesn’t have a property to show line rows. So we should use a `CSS` class and set the bottom border, in this way `border-bottom-color: red !important;`

To test in other versions of ExtJS access [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1m8n&view/editor).

```js
var Grid1Store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email'],
    autoLoad: true,
    data: [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John Smith",
        "email": "jsmith@example.com"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Anna Smith",
        "email": "asmith@example.com"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Peter Smith",
        "email": "psmith@example.com"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Tom Smith",
        "email": "tsmith@example.com"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Andy Smith",
        "email": "asmith@example.com"
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Nick Smith",
        "email": "nsmith@example.com"
    }]
});

var onReadyFunction = function() {

    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        frame: true,
        title: 'Example',
        width: 450,
        height: 200,
        store: Grid1Store,
        columns: [{
            header: "Id",
            dataIndex: 'id',
            width: '50px'
        }, {
            header: "Name",
            dataIndex: 'name',
            width: '150px'
        }, {
            header: "Email",
            dataIndex: 'email',
            width: '200px',
            align: 'center'
        }]
    });
}
Ext.onReady(onReadyFunction);
```

```css
.x-grid-cell {
    border-bottom-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/ext-all.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css")/>
```